# No. of different pairs satisfying the given condition

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

If $|x-y|=1$ and $\frac{x}{y}=xy$, how many unique pairs $(x,y)$ satisfy both these conditions?

I tried solving this problem by the following method:

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{y}&=xy\\
x&=xy^2\\
y^2&=1\\
y&=\pm 1
\end{align}

Since y can be either +1 or -1,

$$|x-(-1)|=1 \Rightarrow x=0$$

or

$$|x-1|=1 \Rightarrow x=2$$

So, I obtained $(0,-1)$ and $(2,1)$ as the solutions. But apparently the answer which is given in the solutions to this problem states $4$ solutions as the answer.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second equation we have $x=xy^2$, which gives $x(y^2-1)=0$. This however does not imply $y^2=1$: it is possible that $x=0$. So we split into three cases, $y=1$, $y=-1$ and $x=0$. In the first case, $x$ can be either $0$ or $2$. In the second case, $x$ can be either $0$ or $-2$. In the third case, $y=\pm1$, but we're lucky that this was already covered in the previous cases.

So the solutions are $(x,y)=(0,1),(2,1),(0,-1),(-2,-1)$. There are four solutions indeed.